# How to minify and factor-bundle files in the same browserify command?

Tags: javascript, browserify, uglifyjs, factor-bundle

I currently have this `factor-bundle` command which I use to bundle my files, and pull everything common into a common file:

```
browserify index.js bar-charts.js list-filter.js dashboard.js 
  -p [ factor-bundle -o ../../static/js/index.js -o ../../static/js/bar-chart.js -o ../../static/js/list-filter.js -o ../../static/js/dashboard.js ] 
  -o ../../static/js/common.js
```

I previously also used this command to uglify individual files:

```
 browserify index.js | uglifyjs > ../../static/js/index.min.js
```

How can I both combine files with `factor-bundle`, and minify them with `uglifyjs`, in the same command?

I found [this example in the factor-bundle docs](https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle#user-content-command-line-outpipe-example), but I don't really understand how to adapt it.

(I could also use two commands, if that works better. I just want to end up with minified and combined files!)

Comment: Why don't you use uglifyify?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have been looking into this area recently and stumbled on what I think might be able to help you.

```
browserify files/*.js \
    -p [ ../ -o 'uglifyjs -cm | tee bundle/`basename $FILE` | gzip > bundle/`basename $FILE`.gz' ] \
    | uglifyjs -cm | tee bundle/common.js | gzip > bundle/common.js.gz
```

I've not dabbled much with browserify but to me this looks as though it is simply piping the output from factor-bundle into uglify.

source: https://gist.github.com/substack/68f8d502be42d5cd4942

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

In order to minify and bundle your files in a single command, you can use the `&&` operator to execute the multiple commands (i.e., `browserify`, `uglifyjs`) in a single line from your terminal.

### Details

To minify each file individually, we could chain multiple `uglifyjs` commands for each file, but a more concise way would be to use the `uglifyjs-folder` module, which allows minifying multiple files individually into a single file/folder (in your case, a folder). The caveat with this module is that we cannot rename the individual files (e.g., `index.js` to `index.min.js`), so if renaming the files is a strict requirement, you could continue using uglifyjs and chain the commands like mentioned above.

Assuming `uglifyjs-folder` is used, I've set the destination of the minified files to a production-ready folder `./static/js/min/` by including `-eo`, where `e` minifies each file independently and `o` specifies the destination folder for the minified files (see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-folder#Documentation) for more information).

### Code

#### Method 1: Terminal Command

Make sure that your dependencies are installed globally on your system (e.g., `npm i -g uglifyjs-folder`). The terminal command is below:

```
browserify index.js bar-charts.js list-filter.js dashboard.js -p [ factor-bundle -o ../../static/js/index.js -o ../../static/js/bar-chart.js -o ../../static/js/list-filter.js -o ../../static/js/dashboard.js ] -o ../../static/js/common.js && uglifyjs-folder ../../static/js -eo ../../static/js/min
```

#### Method 2: NPM Scripts

Alternatively, assuming your project is using npm (or yarn), you can access the `package.json` and refactor your `browserify` and `uglifyjs` commands into separate npm scripts and execute them together by running the terminal command `npm run build` in the root directory of your project (i.e., where `package.json` is located). The npm scripts are defined below:

```
"scripts": {
  "bundle": "browserify index.js bar-charts.js list-filter.js dashboard.js -p [ factor-bundle -o ../../static/js/index.js -o ../../static/js/bar-chart.js -o ../../static/js/list-filter.js -o ../../static/js/dashboard.js ] -o ../../static/js/common.js",
  "minify": "uglifyjs-folder ../../static/js -eo ../../static/js/min",
  "build": "npm run bundle && npm run minify"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Browserify is a tool for bundling JavaScript files, and you can use various plugins to minify and factor-bundle your code. To achieve both minification and factor-bundling in the same Browserify command, you can use the following approach:

First, make sure you have the necessary packages installed:

```
npm install browserify babelify uglify-js factor-bundle --save-dev
```

Assuming you have multiple entry points for your application, let's say main1.js and main2.js, you can use Browserify with factor-bundle and UglifyJS for minification as follows:

```
browserify -e main1.js -p [ factor-bundle -o bundle1.js ] -p [ babelify --presets @babel/preset-env ] | uglifyjs -cm > bundle1.min.js
```

browserify -e main2.js -p [ factor-bundle -o bundle2.js ] -p [ babelify --presets @babel/preset-env ] | uglifyjs -cm > bundle2.min.js

Here's a breakdown of the command:

browserify -e main1.js: Specifies the entry point for the first bundle.
-p [ factor-bundle -o bundle1.js ]: Uses the factor-bundle plugin to create a separate bundle (bundle1.js) for the first entry point.
-p [ babelify --presets @babel/preset-env ]: Uses Babelify to transpile the code, assuming you want to use Babel for ES6+ features.
| uglifyjs -cm > bundle1.min.js: Pipes the output through UglifyJS to minify and compress the code, then saves it to bundle1.min.js.
Repeat the process for the second entry point (main2.js) with appropriate filenames.

This command structure helps you factor-bundle your code into separate files and minify each resulting bundle. Customize the entry points and filenames as per your project structure and requirements.